# What is the best practices for pairing two user in Firebase realtime database?

Tags: mysql, database, firebase, data-structures

I have been thinking about this title for a long time.

If we want to randomly pair two users and don't consider any conditions, What should I do in database structure and code?

Also, if we have many conditions to query the user, is it not suitable for using the Realtime database and I should use MySQL or something else?

I don't have the experiment in this field and like to know how most people would do.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "if we have many conditions to query the use"? What are those conditions?

Comment: Such as gender, city, timestamp, age, VIP, etc. That would be more than five conditions. Thank you.

Comment: While the question is somewhat clear, it's not really a good question for SO. We can assist with existing code issues but asking us to either write code for you or tell you how to structure your app is beyond what we can do here as it would require an extensive dialog. There are 1000 ways to "pair users in Firebase" regardless of many conditions. I would encourage you to give it a try and write some code - getting familiar with Firebase through the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) will really help your understanding of the product.

Comment: Thank you all, I understand the question is not really good here and maybe I will find some way to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a "pairs" node, which lists the pair of each user.

When a user wants to find a pair:

- Add a key-value node to "pairs", where the key is the UID, and the value is an empty string.
- Add a listener to your new node.
- Search in "pairs" for another user that has an empty string as a value.
- If found, change the values of both nodes to the other user's UID.
- When the listener callback will be called, it means some other user just paired with you, so you can use the value to know the UID of the other user. Also, don't forget to cancel the listener.

The reads and writes to the database should be atomic, in order to prevent bugs in the pairing process (like overriding an existing pair). Therefore, you should use
[firebase transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

If there are certain conditions for a pair, you can save the conditions' data in the node of the user, inside the "pairs" node (for temporary data), or inside the "users" node that you probably have already (for long term data).

### Important

**However!**, this method leaks data about the existing pairs, and about the users that are waiting for a pair. I recommend moving the code to your server or to a cloud function. Security is really critical here! You should also write some strict security rules for the database.

Hope I managed to help!

Comment: @TimChiang Please note this answer will not work for the Realtime Database. A node with nil value won't exist so this `key is the UID, and the value is null` isn't possible in the RTDB. While Firebase has a very powerful query engine one thing it cannot do is query for data that doesn't exist - there just isn't a way to do that. So this `Search in "pairs" for another user that has a null value` is not possible in that context. While I appreciate the effort, it's not a correct answer and will lead you down the wrong path. +1 for mentioning transactions though - that's an excellent suggestion.

Comment: @Jay Totally correct. I changed the default value to an empty string (any other value that cannot be a valid UID will also do). Thank you!